# Computer powers up, but doesn't POST. Suggestions?

Tags: boot, motherboard, post

I have a system that powers up. The CD/DVD drive fires up, I can hear the hard drive spin on, and all the fans spin. However, the monitor doesn't display anything. I have made a checklist of things I have done/checked.

- The monitor: it works on another computer, so I don't think that is the problem
- The onboard GPU: I purchased a cheap PCI express GPU, and plugged it in; still no graphics
- The memory: My other system doesn't have the same type of RAM, so I couldn't check if they work on it. I did, however try to turn it on with one stick at a time, but problem persisted. I even removed all the RAM... isn't the motherboard supposed to beep if it doesn't have any RAM?
- Other components (hdd, wifi pci express card, disk drive): Still wouldn't display anything with all of them removed.
- CPU: Incompatible with my other system. Again, after removing it, shouldn't the motherboard beep at me or something?

The fact that the motherboard isn't beeping when I remove the RAM or CPU makes me think it is at fault, except all of the other components (hdd, disk drive, fans, ect.) still turn on. Do you have any suggestions of what I could try next?

Comment: What motherboard? And, just to check: did you try a different monitor cable?

Comment: recent motherboards come without any onboard speakers... check if you have a speaker on your motherboard... if you have heard it beep at other times, it should be fine...

Comment: A friend suggested blown capacitors on the motherboard could be a possible reason.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see anything about the PSU. Get out the ol' multimeter and test the "Power good" pin on the unit. This should be pin 8 and is usually the only grey wire. If the voltage on pin 8 isn't a nice +5v, then the motherboard may not be willing to POST. I've been in the same debacle.